# How to add checkbox in datatable using datagrid view c#

Tags: c#, webforms

```
private void BindQuotationDataToGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("No", typeof(bool)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Number", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));

 dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["No"] = "";
    dr["Item"] = 1;
    dr["Number"] = "485-3AB";
    dr["Name"] = " Light Ring ";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    //Bind the GridView  
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

How to add checkbox in data using boolean for `dr = dt.NewRow();` in C#
I'm stuck at `dr["No"] = "";`

Is there any source I can refer to figure out about this

Comment: A `DataGridView` is a Windows Forms control. You appear to be using a Web Forms `GridView`, which is very different thing.

Comment: You don't add a `CheckBox` to the `DataRow`. You've already specified that the data type of that column is `bool` so set that field to a `bool`, i.e. `true` or `false`. When you bind, I suspect that the grid will display a check box automatically. If it doesn't, that's something you need to configure in the `GridView`. It's nothing to do with the `DataTable`.